# Looking for the reference of a circular 5-pin socket for an optoelectronic component

Tags: components, socket

I am currently using an optoelectronic component (an optic fiber switch) that has the following pinout, and I do not want to solder it directly, to be more flexible, so I am looking for a socket to plug it into.

[image: Socket pinout]
(dimensions in mm)

I already have one, so I know it exists, but it comes from a complete PCB and I would like to buy more of them without all the rest of the circuitry.

[image: Socket I already have]

I can't find anything like it, everything I found has less than 5 pins. The only exception is [from AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000955153039.html), but it is quite expensive, and I would prefer a more reliable source.

[image: AliExpress socket]

I even tried to contact a well-known seller of optoelectronic components (ThorLabs), but they told me they do not have such a socket.

Comment: Are you asking for a source to buy one, or are you asking for the proper name of the socket so that you can search for one?  Asking for a source if off topic (your question will be closed.)  Asking for the proper name is on topic.

Comment: what does the maker of the part call the part package?

Comment: It looks like a 5-pin TO56 socket to me.

Comment: Ha, try looking for "TO-18", "TO-46", "TO-56" all with "5 pin". Those have all the same pin circle diameter. The TO numbers are mixed wildly with different pin counts despite any definition by IPC. If you dont get the right thing bend the pins a bit to match a DIP-6 or DIP-8 socket or even a TO-39, which are simpler to find...